# Azure console app - multiple instances

Tags: azure, console-application

I am new to Azure and have inherited a project that I am trying to fix. Part of the solution is a Web App that starts a Console App which runs continuously. My problem is that there are 2 instances of the Console App runnig and I don't know why. The console log shows this:

...

[03/09/2016 11:11:14 > 2d3880: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[03/09/2016 11:11:14 > e4b3d7: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[03/09/2016 11:11:14 > e4b3d7: INFO] Service layer checks starting up

[03/09/2016 11:11:14 > 2d3880: INFO] Service layer checks starting up

...

I assume the numbers in the log relate to instances but I cannot find any details on the Web.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check in the Web App blade, under Settings > Webjobs and see how many of them are?

Comment: are there two instances of the web app - and each spins up a console app? (in the old azure portal look at Scale and instance count)

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed the problem. For some reason there were 2 instances of the Web App enabled. Now to find out how this happened